# First div transparent background - Angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular

I know that there are few answers related to this topic but I have not found any valid one

I am using `Angular 7` as a Framework and I am dealing with a problem.

I have two components:
- Header
- Landing

**app.component.html**

I have set in my `app.component.html` both of them to show them continuously:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My `header` has a fixed `height` equals to 80px and the `margin-top` of my `router` is also -80px

I thought that I could show the image of my `router` even on the `header` by using `opacity` or `rgba` but the result is not what I expect (I do not get a transparent background on `header` which shows the text on the image)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
 .header{
   text-align: center;
   top: 48.4px;
   position: absolute;
   height: 80px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgba(#ffffff, 0));

 .text{
   margin-top: 40px;
   border-radius: 30px;
   width: 200px;
   }
 }
```

This is scss, u can easily convert it to css by merging if u need. The aim right here is to make `.header` the background of `<header></header>` and the text will be on top the this background. Your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will be overlapped by the header if u give it absolute position and the height you specified!